# PHP file upload gives successful error code, but no image appears

Tags: php, file-upload

For the sake of clarity I'll break this up into easy to navigate and readable sections.

**The Issue:**

The $_FILES super-global doesn't appear to hold any information after I upload a file. Despite this, I get error code 0 (successful upload)  which seems contradictory.

**Background:**

I've been working on a personal website for a while now, and am working on a post management system. It's been going great so far, but I'm stuck fast trying to upload an image using $_FILES.

I've done this kind of thing many times at school and my job, but there appears to be some sort of issue with my computer, or I'm having a massive stroke of idiocy.

**To fix this issue I've already:**

1. Enabled file uploads in php.ini-production for the version I am using (php 7.1.7)
2. Changed values such as `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` to 100m
3. Inspected the error code PHP is returning, returns error code 0, or `UPLOAD_ERR_OK`
4. Checked my own code for any simple mistakes I'm making. I can't see any, but that's usually the case when you have an error.

I'll include a small test page I wrote, and is demonstrating the issue:

**text.php:**

```
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        echo $_FILES['a']['error'];
        if(isset($_FILE['a']['tmp_name'])){
            echo "hello";

        }
    }

    ?>

    <form action = "text.php" method = "POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for = "a"> Send Image </label>
        <input type = "file" name = "a" id = "a">
        <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Submit">
    </form>
```

when the form is submitted, I get error code 0 but the hello test statement *does not* trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global array is named `$_FILES` you are checking for `isset($_FILE['a']['tmp_name']`

And if you want to check for uploaded file try using

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['a']['tmp_name'])) {
   //file is uploaded
}
```

Comment: There you go. I suppose I was right to predict a massive stroke of idiocy. Thanks!